# Crash when using iOS Accessibility with UITableView sections and it would crash after several [tableview reloadData]

Tags: uitableview, crash, accessibility, reloaddata

I was getting a crash when using iOS Accessibility with UITableView sections where the section was an accessibility element and it would crash after several [tableview reloadData].

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the [tableView reloadData] was being called from within a block - in other words being called from another thread.

The simple solution was the following:

```
- (void)blockTest
{
    [self displayData:YES animated:YES onCompletion:^(void) {
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateTableData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }];
}


- (void)updateTableData
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

After that no more crashes.

Comment: [tableView reloadData] was being called from a thread other than the main thread.